# How to get started building web apps with Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I want to start learning Sencha Touch. Being a server side programmer in Java I want to understand kind of classes I need to instantiate and how to structure the application. I don't understand the difference between `Ext.Application` and `Ext.setup` nor if there are other classes to use.

I tried Googling for books, but the books written gets bad reviews on Amazon so I don't want to buy them, the guides/screencast etc on Sencha obviously lacks introduction on where to put the differents part in an application. I am particulary interested in how you make an application with multiple views. Do you make one html5 and one JS file for each view, do you put everything in one file? I can't find one single post saying something on how to do this.

I know MVC very well, but I don't understand how to apply it in Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha Touch is JS Framework built for generating HTML/CSS that feels native on many different mobile devices. The best thing if you want to learn Sencha touch is to see [this quick start tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-touch-quick-start/)! After you take a look at the [learn section for Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/learn/touch/), the best thing would be to get familiar with [Sencha Touch Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/). Here you have description of all classes, methods, events and so on... Also take a look at this books:

- [Extjs in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182110)
- [Learning Extjs 3.2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849511209)
- [Extjs 3.0 cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847198708)

Sencha Touch is bulit on extjs standard, the new Sencha Touch 2 will run on Extjs 4 engine. Enyoy!!!!

Answer (score -2):

This is going to be rough because Sencha Touch is a JavaScript framework that is primarily intended to run in the web browser.

If this is going to be a webapp the first you need to do is build a webpage.  Follow these instructions:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22877/seo-where-do-i-start?answertab=votes#tab-top

Second, you need some basic understanding of JavaScript in order to understand what you are getting into.

- JavaScript does not have classes
- JavaScript has prototypes instead of classes
- JavaScript only has function scope and not block scope
- JavaScript has a bunch of sloppy crap like automatic semicolon insertion
- JavaScript is a lambda language, which gives immediate access to closure.  This is the most powerful and beautiful part of JavaScript.  If you do not understand closure then you will not understand how to take full advantage of the language to do complicated things with a decent amount of performance.

Third, Sencha is a commerical product.  This indicates it will likely have acceptable documentation plus some amount of support.  If this is not the case then **DO NOT BUY IT**.

Forth, MVC is not going to do you any real favors in JavaScript.  The more familiar you become with the language on the client-side you will understand just how distant you are from the data on the server.